# Moving data from azure sql to Databricks

Tags: azure-databricks

I am new to databricks, I am here facing issue in moving data from Azure Sql database to Azure Databricks, can anyone please help me in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to it with the Azure SQL connection string and JDBC.

```
connectionString = "<Azure SQL connection string>"

df = spark.read.jdbc(connectionString, "<Table name>")
```

Quite a few examples can be found on the [documentation](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html#python-example)